# babel-loader: transpile an entry not named app.js?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

we've been using webpack with the babel-loader plugin for transpiling ES for a while. for our development environment, our config file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // When I change the below to app2.js, it's no longer transpiled
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'app.js'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        test: /\.js$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!')),
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(processEnvPlugin),
  ],
  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss', '.css'],
    root: [__dirname],
  },
};
```

I run this with `webpack-dev-server --inline --config=webpack-dev.config.js --content-base='client'`.

Problem is, if I change `app.js` in entry to `app2.js`, or anything else, the file is still served by the webpack server (running on 8080), but is no longer transpiled.

Is there something unique/magical about the name `app.js` in terms of babel-loader? Virtually every example tutorial I can find, including the webpack docs, use the `app.js` convention, but obviously it looks like the name *should* be able to be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not working and that you're checking the right file (**app.js**, always) ? If by *"the file is [...] no longer transpiled"*, you mean that the file named **app2.js** is not transpiled when you GET it, it's expected behavior from what your configuration looks like.

According to your configuration, your transpiled file will always be named **app.js**, regardless of your input file :

```
filename: '[name].js', // => translates to "app.js"
```

`[name]` is replaced by the name of the chunk, which is "app" :

```
 entry: {
    app: ...
 },
```

To avoid confusion between your input and your output, you can name your chunk differently, or simply use an hardcoded name for the ouput, like 'bundle.js'